# In what area the function $\ln(1+z^2)$ is not analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analytic-functions

> If $\ln(z)$ is the main branch of the the logarithm ($-\pi<\arg z<\pi$) then in what area the function $\ln(1+z^2)$ is not analytic ($z$ is a complex number)?

The method to solve this problem as I guess is to separate the real and imaginary parts and use the Cauchy-Riemann equation.
then the areas in which the equation doesn't hold is the answer.
I'm not sure if my method is right, even if it is, I don't know how to separate correctly and get the right result.

Introducing books or websites which explain this topic will be very helpful.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\log(1+z^2)=\log(1+x^2-y^2+2ixy)=\ln\sqrt{(1+x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}+i\arctan\dfrac{2xy}{1+x^2-y^2}$$
then work with
$$u=\dfrac12\ln\left((1+x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2\right)~~~,~~~v=\arctan\dfrac{2xy}{1+x^2-y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining $\ln$ as the main branch of the logarithm, $\ln$ is an analytic function. And since the composition of analytic functions is again an analytic function, your function is analytic. More precisely, if$$D=\mathbb{C}\setminus\bigl\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,1+z^2\notin(-\infty,0]\bigr\},$$then$$\begin{array}{ccc}D&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\z&\mapsto&\ln(1+z^2)\end{array}$$is an analytic function.

Comment: I didn't know that theorem, that the composition of analytic functions is again an analytic function. then how can I prove its analyticity using the Cauchy-Riemann equation? to be more precise: how do I separate the real and the imaginary parts? for $f(z) = \ln(1+z^2) = u + iv$ I want to find u and v, weather in Polar coordinates or Cartesian.

Comment: First, you must be able to express $\ln(x+yi)$ as $u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ with $u(x,y),v(x,y)\in\mathbb R$. Can you do that? Anyway, I don't think that it's worth the effort.

Comment: I have no problem with that: $$ln(z)=ln(re^{i\theta})=ln(r)+ln(e^{i\theta})=ln(r)+i\theta$$ and then $u=ln(r)$  and $v=\theta$ but when it comes to $ln(1+z^2)$ and don't know to to do with the one.

Comment: @Ewindar Yes. Thats' in polar coordinates. But I wrote $\ln(x+yi)$.

Comment: I can convert that from Polar to Cartesian, but can't do that directly.

Comment: @Ewindar Then you don't know how to express $\ln\bigl(1+(x+yi)^2\bigr)$ as $u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$. That's one of the reasons why I wrote that it's not worth the effort.

Comment: You said I must be able to separate the two parts in Cartesian, but I don't think that's necessary. it would be fine just to do that in Polar.

Comment: @Ewindar But Cauchy-Riemann equations are meant to be used with cartesian coordinates. If you accept to work only in the region $\operatorname{Re}z>0$, you can use$$\ln(x+yi)=\ln\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigr)+\arctan\left(\frac yx\right).$$